# Rename Blackberry Enterprise Server

Tags: bes

I've got a server running BES 5 that I'd like to rename.  Does anyone have any docs on how to do this?  I haven't found anything on RIMs site or when searching.

UPDATE: In my case the SQL databases are on another server which is a dedicated SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A similar question was asked on Experts Exchange http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Handhelds_-_PDAs/Blackberry/Q_23919386.html

Apparently, RIM says it's a bad idea to rename the server. It breaks SQL stuff (which is dependent on the system name). There may be ways to fix that, but the sure way of doing this is to install on a new server and migrate the accounts over. BES Express 5 with the Blackberry Enterprise Transporter makes the process really easy. If you're running in VMs, it's even easier.

Comment: Fixing the SQL name change is actually very easy, just 2 lines of T/SQL and a restart of the SQL Service will take care of that.  I should have included, but forgot to, that the SQL databases aren't on this machine.  Apparently EE has fixed the site so that if you come in from the outside you can't see everything.  Everything is a VM, so building a new BES shouldn't be tough. Sounds like a new VM is my best option. Was hoping for an easier solution.

Answer (score -3):

As much as I like to have all the servers fit a naming convention I find that the cons often outweigh the pros. Try renaming it and if things don't break that's great and if things do just revert (doesn't always work this way).  If you have free time continue with this move but my guess is that if you take a moment to look things over there are much better things you can do with your time.

Having the servers fit a naming convention will only help IT feel good.
Having the BES server down for sometime will only hurt everyone with a BB.

Comment: -1 I'm sorry. I really didn't want to downvote because your intentions were pure. I just don't think an appropriate answer in a production environment is "change it and see if it breaks anything"

Comment: @Jason - damnit that means I have to re-think my deployment strategy for pretty much **everything** now... :(

Comment: @Farseeker - I always thought you Aussies had things all backwards. Your toilets don't flush in the correct direction, your summer is winter and your winter is summer. Now I find out you make changes before testing...all my suspicions are confirmed in you.

Comment: @Jason - the toilet/sink thing is a myth. My sink swirls in whatever direction it damn well pleases - depends on which side of the sink hole I have the spout pointing to. And having summer in Dec -> February means that our summer holidays cover Christmas and NewYear, which means that's when our summer breaks are, which means that we get a looong holiday over Christmas rather than just a few days.

Comment: @Farseeker - But I saw it on The Simpsons. Are you saying that the TV lied to me?

Comment: @Jason, well... The Simpsons is a Fox program, which is owned by... Fox, which is owned by Rupert Murdoch, and he's an Australian (one we don't really like though), so I guess it MUST be true

Comment: -1 There's no way I'm going to rename it and see what happens.  If I was willing to do that, I would have done that instead of posting a question here about it.

Comment: If I can't rename it and I can't easily migrate it to a new host with a correct name, I can't do recovery either and that's a situation I don't like to be in. So if it breaks on something as basic as this, it needs to be researched and broken under control before it breaks unexpectedly outside of control imo ^^ If it means reinstalling the server, fine, good DR practice, ne? ^^